# Expression must have a pointer to object type in C 2

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

```
void ArrayCal();

int main(void)
{
    ArrayCal();//calling fun.
    return 0;
    system("pause");
}

void ArrayCal()//this fun will scan elements into (Arr) the array of pointer
{
    int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0, row = 0;
    printf("Enter numbers of rows: ");
    scanf("%d", &row);//scan rows
    int* Arr = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*row);//to add more memory into the Arr
        for (a = 0; a < row; a++)
        {
            printf("\nEnter array length for row %d: ", a + 1);
            scanf("%d", &b);//scan length
            *(Arr + a) = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*b);//to add more memory into the arrays

            for (c = 0; c < b; c++)
            {
                printf("\nEnter value for array: ");
                scanf("%d", Arr[row][b]);//scan value
            }
        }
    sortPrint(Arr);//calling fun. to print the Arr

    free(Arr);//to free the memory of the Arr.
    for (a = 0; a < row; a++)
    {
        free(*(Arr + a));//to free the memory of the arrays 
    }
}
```

I'm trying to scan elements into array of pointer and I don't know why I have this bug.

Comment: You forgot to mention __where__ the error occurs. And it's not a bug, it's a compilation error.

Comment: You should never cast the result of malloc.

Comment: 1) `int* Arr = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*row);` --> `int** Arr = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*)*row);`

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems likely that you are using a bad source for learning C programming, who is trying to "teach" you how to "dynamically allocate 2D arrays".

Comment: Also, you need to get a better compiler or enable warnings on the one you are using. Code such as `return 0; system("pause");` shouldn't pass without warnings on any half-decent compiler.

Comment: You need to have `int **Arr` for that to work; also; you're using the `Arr` after it has been freed which is a *grave* error. Also `Arr[row][b]`, even when `Arr` is a double-star, isn't a pointer, and `scanf` wouldn't work. All in all, how could you write all of this code when even the simpler parts wouldn't compile there - please try to compile more often in the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

This is not how you allocate pointer-based look-up tables. You need to allocate an array of pointers first, and then set every pointer in that array to point at allocated memory.

The code in the question of [Correctly allocating multi-dimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays) shows how to allocate this properly. However, as the answer to that question demonstrates, this is most likely the wrong method to use in the first place.